# Why doesn't admin styles load in Laravel 10 in production?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, adminlte

I'm a newbie with laravel and I'm having problems that I hope you can help me to fix.

It is a project that I have locally with Laravel v10.9.0 (PHP v8.1.10).
I have AdminLte installed with [https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have moved the project to a server that is managed and to which I have no console access (I can't run php artisan).

The laravel home page is the default one for the installation, I have only worked on the backend part of the project and the styles are loaded without problem.

But when I enter some of the paths that I have locally that load the admin dashboard the styles are not loaded.
Looking at the code I see the following style, in my project in local, mydomain.com/vendor/adminlte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css and if I access to this domain I see all the css code.

However if I do the same on the web server I don't see anything, it doesn't give any error, but the page is blank. On the web server if I modify the url and before /vendor I put /public to get mydomain.com/public/vendor/adminlte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css I see the css with all the styles.

Can anyone know what is going on? I cleared the caches manually, config, views, routes, but everything is still the same.
Thanks!

I cleared the caches manually, config, views, routes, but everything is still the same.

Comment: How did you deploy the project? If you cant run `php artisan` commands, does that mean all commands like npm, git, etc? Did you copy paste the project from local to production? zip/unzip?

Comment: The deployment was done with zip unzip and then I edited the .env with the app url and the database data.
I made a small modification adding /public to the domain to make it ttps://mydomain.com/public and so it loads everything without problem, although the /public appears in the public url and I don't like it. Isn't there any way to put this redirect in the htaccess?
In my local version I didn't have any htaccess so I don't know if I have to add one by default.
Thanks

Comment: You have not provided any code that we can work on. You also did not specify which server(aws, heroku, IIS, etc) you deployed the project. btw, what do you mean you can't run artisan commands? cant open terminal? need sudo?

Comment: there is too little info for us to diagnose.

Comment: I solved with

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Thanks!!